# Does anyone have a working solidity swap example for a UniSwap v2 on Ropsten in Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap, defi, swaps

Does anyone have a working solidity swap example for a UniSwap v2 on Ropsten in Remix?

I've read these article:
https://soliditydeveloper.com/uniswap2#comment-5084771054

And this post:
[Swap ether to tokens on Uniswap V2 Router 02 fails](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84639/swap-ether-to-tokens-on-uniswap-v2-router-02-fails/84640#84640)

This example is for Kovan and it doesn't seem to work on Ropsten. I can't seem to find a working faucet for Koven to try this out.

When every I attempt to call any function in Remix I get the following warning...

Gas estimation failed

"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted"

This may be because the DAI address on Ropsten could be different.

If anyone has a working example they can share that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Does this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/104054/uniswap-v2-running-out-of-gas-when-deploying-the-factory-on-ganache fix the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not but thanks for the reply.